# Апостроф в українській мові

Tags: правопис, orthography

Чому слова возз'єднання, арф'яр, черв'як пишуться з апострофом, а такі слова як медвяний, карбюратор без апострофа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Український правопис 2015

[§ 6. Апостроф](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par6)

> 1. Після губних приголосних (б, п, в, м, ф): *б’ю, п’ять, п’є, в’язи, у здоров’ї, м’ясо, рум’яний, тім’я, мереф’янський, В’ячеслав,
>      Стеф’юк.*
>
> ***Примітка.*** Апостроф не пишеться, коли перед губним звуком є приголосний
>   (крім р), який належить до кореня: *дзвякнути, мавпячий, свято,
>   тьмяний, цвях*; але: *верб’я, торф’яний, черв’як.*
>
> Коли такий приголосний належить до префікса, то апостроф пишеться, як
>   і в тих же словах без префікса: зв’язок, зв’ялити, підв’язати,
>   розм’якшити.